# SQL Server minimum of all positive values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
tblMembers
ID   Credit  Is_Member
---  ---     --- 
1    45      True
2    20      False
3    25      True
4    -10     True
5    -5      False
6    13      True
```

How can I create a view showing the record with the (Minimum Positive) value of **Credit** and **Is_Member**="True"?

Answer (score 3):

You'd use a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblMembers
WHERE Credit = (SELECT MIN(Credit)
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE Is_Member = TRUE AND Credit > 0)
AND Is_Member = TRUE
```

Note that multiple rows could be tied for the lowest positive value, so you may get more than one result.

Answer (score 2):

```
select min(credit) 
from tblMembers
where Is_Member = 'true'
    and credit > 0
```

...and if this is homework, please tag it as such (as answers may be different).

**EDIT**

Didn't read the question correctly.

```
select * from tblMembers
where credit = (select min(credit)
    from tblMembers
    where credit > 0
        and Is_Member = 'true')
and Is_Member = 'true'
```

...you need the check for Is_Member = 'true' in both spots because the lowest credit score may not be a member (which would net no results) AND a non-member and member may share the lowest score but only a member should show.

Comment: Justin - I think the "Is_Member = true" needs to go inside the sub select.  Otherwise if the person with the lowest credit isn't a member, you'll get no results back.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the catch. You need it in both queries...if you take it away on the outer query, you may get non-members that have a score equal to the lowest member.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple records that meet this criteria...

```
SELECT *
FROM tblMembers
WHERE Credit = (
    SELECT  MIN(Credit)
    WHERE   Credit > 0
        AND Is_Member = 'True'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tblMembers
WHERE Credit = 
(SELECT MIN(Credit) FROM tblMembers WHERE Credit > 0 AND Is_Member = 'True')
AND Is_Member = 'True'
```

Note that if you have more than one row with the same (minimum) credit, that would return more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

You are liable to have multiple records that fit your criteria.  If you only want a single row:

```
create view PositiveCreditMember
as
select top 1
    ID
,   credit
,   is_member
from
    tblMembers
where 
    credit in (
      select
         min(Credit) 
      from
         tblMembers
      where
        credit > 0
        and is_member = 'True'
    )
    and is_member = 'True'
order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? It seems straightforward enough:

```
select min(Credit) as Credit 
from tblMembers 
where Is_Member = 'True' and Credit >= 0
```

Comment: You're only showing the minimum credit and not the record with the lowest positive credit (See Solution by Justin Niessner)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(Credit), ID FROM tblMembers WHERE Is_Member="True"
GROUP BY ID HAVING MIN(Credit) > 0
```

I think I might be oversimplifying this, though.  Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
select * from credit
where is_member = 'true'
and   credit > 0
order by credit
limit 1
```

aka

```
select top 1 * from credit
where is_member = 'true'
and   credit > 0
order by credit
```

depending on your flavor of SQL.  This gives only one record; as others have said there may be multiple records with the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
CREATE VIEW vwXYZ
AS
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tblMembers
WHERE [Is_Member] = 1
AND Credit > 0
ORDER BY Credit;
```

This eliminates the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one of the matching rows at random:

```
select top 1 * from tblMembers where Is_Member = 1 order by credit
```

or if you want all the matching rows:

```
select top 1 with ties * from tblMembers where Is_Member = 1 order by credit
```